# While starting NIFI.. getting Exception: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./state/local/partition-0/107654.journal: Too many open files

Tags: apache-nifi

While starting NiFi  it  fails with below error

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:55)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flowController': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is **java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: ./state/local/partition-0/107654.journal: Too many open files**
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)

i Debuged and found there are alot of file created in all the partition in

/usr/lib/NiFi/NiFi/nifi-1.11.4/state/local

partition-0   partition-11  partition-14  partition-3  partition-6  partition-9
partition-1   partition-12  partition-15  partition-4  partition-7  snapshot
partition-10  partition-13  partition-2   partition-5  partition-8  wali.lock

like if any partition folder i select ... suppose i select partition-0 so inside that lots of journal entry i can see like

107018.journal  107632.journal  108246.journal  108860.journal  109474.journal  110088.journal
107019.journal  107633.journal  108247.journal  108861.journal  109475.journal  110089.journal
107020.journal  107634.journal  108248.journal  108862.journal  109476.journal  110090.journal
107021.journal  107635.journal  108249.journal  108863.journal  109477.journal  110091.journal
107022.journal  107636.journal  108250.journal  108864.journal  109478.journal  110092.journal
107023.journal  107637.journal  108251.journal  108865.journal  109479.journal  110093.journal
107024.journal  107638.journal  108252.journal  108866.journal  109480.journal  110094.journal
107025.journal  107639.journal  108253.journal  108867.journal  109481.journal  110095.journal
107026.journal  107640.journal  108254.journal  108868.journal  109482.journal  110096.journal
107027.journal  107641.journal  108255.journal  108869.journal  109483.journal  110097.journal
107028.journal  107642.journal  108256.journal  108870.journal  109484.journal  110098.journal
107029.journal  107643.journal  108257.journal  108871.journal  109485.journal  110099.journal
107030.journal  107644.journal  108258.journal  108872.journal  109486.journal  110100.journal
107031.journal  107645.journal  108259.journal  108873.journal  109487.journal  110101.journal
107032.journal  107646.journal  108260.journal  108874.journal  109488.journal  110102.journal
107033.journal  107647.journal  108261.journal  108875.journal  109489.journal  110103.journal
107034.journal  107648.journal  108262.journal  108876.journal  109490.journal  110104.journal
107035.journal  107649.journal  108263.journal  108877.journal  109491.journal  110105.journal

Entries are even more and i guess this is leading to not start the Nifi .

Hope i find a solution here for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the [instructions to raise the open file limit](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#configuration-best-practices) on your operating system? NiFi requires a high number of open files when reading/writing to the internal data repositories, so if this is limited, it can often prevent successful operation.

From the docs:

> **Maximum File Handles**
>
> NiFi will at any one time potentially have a very
> large number of file handles open. Increase the limits by editing
> `/etc/security/limits.conf` to add something like
>
> - `hard  nofile  50000`
> - `soft  nofile  50000`
>
> **Maximum Forked Processes**
>
> NiFi may be configured to generate a significant number of threads. To increase the allowable
> number, edit `/etc/security/limits.conf`
>
> - `hard  nproc  10000`
> - `soft  nproc  10000`
>
> And your distribution may require an edit to `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf` by adding
>
> - `soft  nproc  10000`

Comment: Thanks it worked , i will try to apply nifi best practices further :)